# ¿es posible editar archivo properties con cualquier editor texto?

Tags: java, archivo-de-propiedades

Es posible una vez creado el archivo jar, con su respectivo archivo **properties**, abrir el **properties** con algún **editor de texto** como el Wordpad y visualizar las claves y valores además de modificar los valores. O sea que la idea es modificar valores sin tener que volver a compilar (crear jar)

Comment: sip, es formato en texto plano.. y los editores lo entienden.... si el archivo es llama x.properties, digamos. Bueno... cualquier editor **decente**.... ahora que dices Wordpad... que es de Microsoft, así que _sin garantías_.

Comment: si? la verdad es que todavía no intenté, ahora pruebo y te comento. Pero entonces cualquier persona malintencionada digamos puede acceder a la información ademas de modificarla, o sea que allí no se debería guardar info sensible como por ej una clave de usuario?

Comment: Si puedes. Si quieres evitar que pueda ser cambiado de forma malintencionada tienes que hacer cosas como firmar digitalmente.

Comment: Y ya que la información sea sensible y no la quieres poner en un archivo de texto plano implica buscar estrategias para no hacerlo.

Comment: si, ahi lo pude abrir, editar y hacer lo que quiera jaj. Si, me va a convenir mandar algunos datos sensibles a la db mejor

Comment: la db tambien se puede abrir y manipular... tal vez si aclaras mejor tu escenario (sin que la pregunta termine basada en opiniones) podamos ayudarte mas.. y si no, date una vuelta por el [chat]

Comment: Para almacenar valores sensibles están las variables de entorno, esas son más difíciles de ver por personas malintencionadas

Answer (score 0):

Es posible, pero no es practico en la mayoria de los casos.

Una de las grandes ventajas del formato es que puedes tener un almacenamiento en formato clave-valor, y si bien podrias tener un archivo properties afuera de tu jar, la practica as comun a nivel empresarial es guardar las opciones de configuracion en una base de datos, esto debido a que:

- hacer cambios no nos obliga a reinicar la aplicacion
- los SGBD estan altamente optimizados
- algunos SGBD proveen interfaces avanzadas para manipular informacion
- se pueden centralizar las configuraciones, teniendo que configurar una sola vez
- se previenen errores en caso de que alguien modifique/elimine erroneamente el archivo de configuracion